# Regarding help text over hover in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

net website i want to put help tex with question mark..how is that possible..
I have seen this in few of sites
like they have (?) when hover on it it shows some help text..How can i do this..
please help me out

Comment: Please post some code or a description of things you have tried.  Your question shows little effort.

Comment: Has nothing to do with .net.  It's just a javascript hover thing i'm sure.

Comment: It's just a matter of using css :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a.help{
    cursor:help
}
```

On your `a` tag that you want the help icon to show, give it the class `.help`, and it will display the `?` cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in HTML, CSS or Javascript.
The simplest would be via HTML using the `title` attribute

```
<div title="help with html">Help (HTML)</div>
```

For the CSS implementation take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/xfzXD/

There are many Javascript options just search for [javascript tooltip](http://google.com/search?q=javascript%20tooltip) and one example is 
[Tipped](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/tipped)